# ASP.NET webkit command causing blockquote in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webkit

We are dynamically creating ordered & unordered listings (OL&UL) using ASP.NET.
It works fine but in chorme when we use the "Text Indent" to create sub listings it creates a BLOCKQUOTE.

This is the webkit command that we are using to create sub listing.

```
document.execCommand('indent', false, null);
```

And here is the result on chrome.

```
<ol>
<li><span>This is Line One</span></li>
<li><blockquote><span>This is Line Two</span></blockquote></li>
<li><span>This is Line Three</span></li>
</ol>
```

And here is the result on Mozilla.

```
<ol>
<li><span>This is Line One</span>
    <ol><li><blockquote><span>This is Line Two</span></blockquote></li></ol>
</li>
<li><span>This is Line Three</span></li>
</ol>
```

The issue happens when we add certain CSS properties to **SPAN** tag present in **LI** such as  **"Float:right"** or **Postion:absolute**
We are unable to find the cause of this problem and need your help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is not yet a standard for *exactly* what `execCommand('indent')` should do, but the consensus seems to be:

- If the selection is in a list, indent by wrapping the selected list items in their own new sublist.
- Otherwise, wrap the selection in `<blockquote>`.

This seems like a reasonable thing to do, until you start to consider pathological cases!

Suppose you have a list item which contains an absolute-positioned DIV, which in turn contains lines of text. You select a line of text and click [Indent].

- Would you expect the entire DIV to be indented in its own new sublist?
- Or would you expect the selected line of text to be wrapped in `<blockquote>` to set it apart from the other lines of text? *(as a user, that's what **I** would expect)*

The Chrome developers chose the `<blockquote>` behaviour.

In your case, there isn't a DIV element involved, but you are achieving the same effect with CSS.

My workaround solution to your problem is to suspend the CSS just long enough to perform the indentation, then enable it again:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<style>
  li span { float:right }      /* Chrome has issues! */
  #editarea .nofloatspan li span { float:inherit }
  #editarea  { border:2px solid blue }
</style>
</head><body>
<div id="editarea" contenteditable="true">
<ol id="ol">
  <li><span>This is Line One</span></li>
  <li><span>This is Line Two</span></li>
  <li><span>This is Line Three</span></li>
</ol>
Not-a-list Line One<br>
Not-a-list Line Two<br>
Not-a-list Line Three<br><br>
</div><br>
<button onclick="indent()">Indent</button> &nbsp;
<button onclick="viewsource()">View Source</button><br>
<textarea id="ta" rows="20" cols="80"></textarea>
<script>
var editarea = document.getElementById("editarea");
function indent() {
  editarea.className = "nofloatspan";          // workaround for Chrome
  document.execCommand('indent', false, null);
  editarea.className = null;                  
}
function viewsource() {
  document.getElementById("ta").value=editarea.innerHTML
}
</script>
</body></html>
```